# Can I meditate as often as I want in The Witcher 3?

Tags: the-witcher-3

In locations and situations where I can meditate, is there a limit on the time between each meditation?

For example, may I meditate, do a fight soon after, then meditate again, without any negative consequences on my ability to meditate and/or regain stats later in the game?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no restriction on amount of meditation - the only restriction on meditating is that you can't do it whilst "in danger" (which is admittedly a bit oddly judged sometimes).

There are no negative side effects to meditating as often as you'd like, though.

Comment: Thanks. Does it mean you don't waste alcholics if you're already full?

Comment: That's correct - you only use alcohol if you have expended potions / bombs since your last meditation.

Comment: Don't forget that you can't meditate "in air", which of course makes sense. And I'm not 100% sure, but I'm guessing you can't meditate on Roach.

Comment: I might have been wrong (and frankly I play on lower difficulty levels so maybe that's relevant here too), but I think that even when it refuses to let me meditate because I'm in danger ("you can't do that now"), it still consumes my alcohol and top up my potions and bombs. That is, I believe I've successfully used meditation to top up my potions and bombs even though I didn't actually meditate for any time duration.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Sometimes I see this happen too and I play on Death March. To me it seems this happens mostly when you are in a mission at a the point where resting is impossible (because you are following someone for instance) and you are not in danger but I could be wrong.